# Screenshot Entire Environment from Browser

Tags: java, google-chrome-extension, applet, firefox-addon, screenshot

I have an internal web application and I want to be able to take a screenshot of the user's entire desktop environment through the app, not just the browser window. In my research, I've found that I could do this using a Java applet. However, Java applets are no longer supported in Chrome as of v45, and they tend to be slow and dated. I've explored the possibility of using flash or a browser extension, but it appears that I would only be able to capture the browser window through these means. I'd prefer not to use a native application, as the screen capture is to be a feature of the web app, so I'd like to keep them as tightly coupled as possible.

Specifically, are there any other methods that I am missing to achieve what I'd like to do? I've sort of resided myself to a java applet sans chrome support or a separate native app, but I've had trouble finding literature online about my use case (assumably due to the security concerns).

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture